# MS SQL # в названии таблиц

Tags: sql-server

Доброе утро, возник вопрос в выгрузке данных из БД, но на сколько мой уровень знаний подсказывает мне что # нельзя использовать в названии, и при выполнении запроса в MS SQL SM Stodio ошибок не создает но и таблицу новую тоже не создает

Данный скрипт был предыдущего администратора БД

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_houses') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp_houses; 
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_plats') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp_plats; 

CREATE TABLE #tmp_houses (
      fh_id int,      
      fias VARCHAR(500),      
      mo_caption  VARCHAR(255),
      city_name VARCHAR(255),
      ul_name VARCHAR(255), 
      d_name  VARCHAR(255),
      d numeric(13, 0),

      opl numeric(18, 2), 
      plat numeric(18, 2),

      area_total numeric(18, 2),
      area_live numeric(18, 2),
      area_non_live numeric(18, 2),

      ss_type VARCHAR(255),
      ss_date date
      )
```

Comment: `#` используется для именования временных таблиц. Если вы работаете в SSMS, то при создании такой таблице в списке таблиц БД она видна не будет. Тем не менее таблица будет создана и время ее жизни будет ограничено сеансом вашего подключения, область ее видимости тоже ограничено вашим сеансом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это локальная временная таблица которая доступна только в скрипте (или процедуре) в котором она вызывается. Если скрипт будет запущен одновременно несколько раз то для каждого скрипта будет создана своя таблица и данные между ними пересекаться не будут. По окончании работы скрипта таблица будет удалена.

Comment: точно только в скрипте, а не во всем текущем сеансе/сессии-то ?

Comment: скорее всего только в скрипте, но я уже с mssql три года не работал, могу что то напутать, проверьте и убедитесь.

Comment: мне не надо проверять, я и так знаю, что на сессию. написал, чтобы вы озадачились этим вопросом.

Comment: за исключением, когда временная таблица создается в хранимке. тогда она удаляется по завершении этой хранимки